# get latest 5 files in directory listing by date

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I have this for getting the files in order by date but how do I get the most recent 5 files in a list regardless if there is not 5:

```
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(Settings.SharedDirectory, "*.log").OrderByDescending(d => new FileInfo(d).LastWriteTime);
    foreach (var directory in files)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(directory);
    }
```

I know how to get the `.Last` but I need the last 5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `.Take(5)`.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: dangit take!!! I was trying to remember how I did that before and couldn't find it. Ty!